# How To Pass JS Array Variable to Modal instead of HTML URL

Tags: javascript, php

The code below displays a track list. It is properly passing the JS variable to the URL and displays the proper track ID on each of the tracks in the list when you rollover the font icon fa-heart, but I need it instead to pass the variable to the pop up modal.

```
<span>
<a href='move_track.php?track="+val.sources[0].track_id+"' 
    data-toggle='modal' data-dismiss='modal'>
<i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true' 
    data-toggle='tooltip' data-container='body' data-placement='top' title='Move to Different Playlist'>
</i></a>
</span>
```

The basic logic I am after is something like:

```
<span>
<a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#moveTrack?track="+val.sources[0].track_id+"' 
data-toggle='modal' data-dismiss='modal'>
<i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='tooltip' 
data-container='body' data-placement='top' title='Move to Different Playlist'>
</i></a></span>
```

**moveTrack** is the name of my pop up modal. this is where I want to catch the variable with a php GET statement...

Is something like this possible within a modal call?

```
data-target='#moveTrack?track="+val.sources[0].track_id+"'
```

Comment: if you want to load the track info into a modal, you should send an ajax request (on click) over a track list item. The ajax request will pass the track id to a php script that will return the track info as json, then (on success) of the ajax request you can load the track info into the modal and open it.

Comment: All i need is the track ID passed

Comment: Can you show your model code where you using the track ID ?